# Apache CXF Exception: SSL connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I have an Apache CXF client which calls an SSL Service.

I randomly get this exception when calling a method on the service client:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error getting a ticket for an external resource. Error 0: SSL connection unexpectedly closed
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:46)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:114)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:800)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1590)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1488)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1307)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
... 58 more
```

Does someone have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your client is working properly but receiving an error from the server side. You can enable [message logging](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html) to see the underlying XML but I would take a look at the logfiles on the server side.